# add main attribute to json object in python

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary, element, addition

I want to add main attribute to json objects. Please see the python code, json objects and expected outcomes below.

**data.json**

```
    [{
       "Full Address": "data1",
       "p1": "1",
       "p2": "6"  
      },
      {
      "Full Address": "data2",
      "p1": "1",
      "p2": "6"
    }]
```

**expected outcomes**

```
    [{
    "fields": {
      "Full Address": "data1",
      "p1": "1",
      "p2": "6"
       }
     },
     {
   "fields": {
    "Full Address": "data2",
    "p1": "1",
    "p2": "6"
   }
   }]
```

**code**

```
import json
with open("data.json", 'r') as json_file:
 json_decoded = json.load(json_file)
for x in json_decoded:
 x['fields'] = ''
 with open("output.json", 'w') as json_out_file:
 json.dump(json_decoded, json_out_file, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False)
```

with this code I am able to add elements inside json objects, but my expected results is different.

output of my code is

```
   [
     {
      "Full Address": "data1",
      "p1": "1",
      "p2": "6",
      "fields": " "
     },
     {
    "Full Address": "data2",
    "p1": "1",
    "p2": "6",
    "fields": " "
    }
  ]
```

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNSpX.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import json

d = [
    {
        "Full Address": "data1",
        "p1": "1",
        "p2": "6"
    },
    {
        "Full Address": "data2",
        "p1": "1",
        "p2": "6"
    },
]

print(json.dumps([{"fields": {**i}} for i in d], indent=2))
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "fields": {
      "Full Address": "data1",
      "p1": "1",
      "p2": "6"
    }
  },
  {
    "fields": {
      "Full Address": "data2",
      "p1": "1",
      "p2": "6"
    }
  }
]
```